# Transmission GTK errors - syslog contains millions (literally) of errors daily and in app labels and layouts regularly become confused

Tags: gtk, syslog, transmission

I have transmission running on this computer loading at startup. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and have installed latest updates.

When I access the app to inspect torrent properties the labels on the windows and tabs become confused often showing text from elsewhere instead of the correct information

[Example of incorrect labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOjPt.png)

When I examine syslog (for other reasons) I find it is full of GTK errors from transmission. There are literally millions of the daily! I include a sample

> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkComboBox'
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_combo_box_get_model: assertion 'GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_combo_box_get_active_iter: assertion 'GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_tree_model_iter_nth_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_MODEL (tree_model)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_unblock: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkSpinButton'
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_spin_button_get_value: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON (spin_button)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_block: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_spin_button_set_value: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON (spin_button)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_unblock: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_block: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkComboBox'
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_combo_box_get_model: assertion 'GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_combo_box_get_active_iter: assertion 'GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_tree_model_iter_nth_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_MODEL (tree_model)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_unblock: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkSpinButton'
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON (spin_button)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_block: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_spin_button_set_value: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON (spin_button)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_unblock: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkSpinButton'
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON (spin_button)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_block: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_spin_button_set_value: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON (spin_button)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer
> Nov  7 10:54:32 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: g_signal_handler_unblock: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
> Nov  7 10:54:34 Martha transmission-gt[1931]: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'

I am assuming that these are different manifestations of the same problem.

Also Transmission regularly crashes but given all these errors this is hardly surprising!

Anyone got any suggestions as to what is wrong, how to fix etc

Any help welcomed

Thanks